# How to deserialize an Object from Map (DART)

Tags: json, dart, serialization

how can I re-create objects from a serialized/deserialized map of objects?

```
import 'dart:convert';

class InternalTx {
  int a;
  bool b;

  InternalTx(this.a, this.b);

  factory InternalTx.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      InternalTxFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => InternalTxToJson(this);
}

InternalTx InternalTxFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => InternalTx(
      json['a'] as int,
      json['b'] as bool,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> InternalTxToJson(InternalTx instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'a': instance.a,
      'b': instance.b,
    };

main() {
  Map<String, InternalTx> m = {};
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    InternalTx itx = InternalTx(i, false);
    m["Hello: $i"] = itx;
  }
  
  String serM = jsonEncode(m);
  print(serM);
  
  ////SERILIZED OKAY
  
  Map<String, dynamic> n = jsonDecode(serM);
  InternalTx newItx = n["Hello: 0"];      <-- Problem here.
  print(newItx);
}
```

Output:

```
{"Hello: 0":{"a":0,"b":false},"Hello: 1":{"a":1,"b":false},"Hello: 2":{"a":2,"b":false},"Hello: 3":{"a":3,"b":false},"Hello: 4":{"a":4,"b":false},"Hello: 5":{"a":5,"b":false},"Hello: 6":{"a":6,"b":false},"Hello: 7":{"a":7,"b":false},"Hello: 8":{"a":8,"b":false},"Hello: 9":{"a":9,"b":false}}
Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of '_JsonMap': type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of type 'InternalTx'
```

What is missing here to deserialize the map of objects correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call the `InternalTx.fromJson` constructor since this is not done automatically. So your last piece of code should be:

```dart
  ////SERILIZED OKAY
  Map<String, dynamic> n = jsonDecode(serM);
  InternalTx newItx = InternalTx.fromJson(n["Hello: 0"]);
  print(newItx); // Instance of 'InternalTx'
```

Comment: Thanks! However... it is somehow confusing, because jsonEncode(a) serialized the Map and the objects automatically, while jsonDecode(serM) is not doing it... only deserializes the Map. Okay.... jsonDecode obviously does not know the class which belongs to the deserialized object.